# Filter textbox to copy only numbers

Tags: vb.net, filter, textbox, numbers

I still newbie in VB programming and I have a question. I wanted to make a filter for countries so then french people download my app and start it, I want then they start program, this program identify their country and translate program to their language (french). I maked translation and country but I have some problems with 2 things.

I use this code to get their IPv4 (external)

> ```
> Using wb As New WebClient
> Dim s As String = wb.DownloadString("http://www.whatsmyip.us/showipsimple.php")
> TextBox1.Text = s
> End Using
> ```

How can I make that then textbox will receive it, filtre to receive only IP (without document.write("");)

After textbox receive IP, with this app (http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) programm will need to receive date from api site (I will use code like above) but I still have same problem. Can I filter OK;;xx.xxx.xx.xxx;US;UNITED STATES to receive only US or UNITED STATES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim s As String = "OK;;xx.xxx.xx.xxx;US;UNITED STATES"
Dim aux() As String = s.Split(";"c)
Dim countryCode As String = aux(3)
Dim countryName As String = aux(4)
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
Dim s As String = "OK;;xx.xxx.xx.xxx;US;UNITED STATES"
Dim countryName = s.SubString(s.LastIndexOf(";"c) + 1)
```

Comment: You forgot your Split character in your function-call.

Comment: Thanks for code. Second code worked fine :D but correct code is LastIndexOf :D

Comment: I market as accepted but I don't have 15 rep and can't up vote. I'm srry. Thanks a lot for help. Now I can make this program work :D.